How does one find historic prices for goods?
I need to find out the typical price of two things - namely bottled water (ie: a plastic individual-size bottle of still drinking water), and, gas-station type road maps - around 1995, in the USA.
(I was very much alive then, but I simply can't recall clearly.)
I assumed I could just instantly search "historic prices year by year, for item X" but I am surprised to find that no such resource exists.
There's plenty of info on inflation as such, and price series for a few marker items (like "butter"), but, again, I was surprised there just does not seem to be, I could not find anyway, such data on this-or-that consumer item.
The bottled water fad had kicked in by then. (Example, Dasani, coke's bottled tap water, was released 1999; I thought I would be able to easily find the retail price of that on launch, but I couldn't even find that.)
In re road maps - the type which in the old days, you bought in a gas station en route - bizarrely I have a large collection of old ones myself, including many USA ones, but couldn't find one with a price; nor could I find an online pic of one, from the year, showing the price.
With bottled water it's further tricky in that, just as today, the supermarket price versus convenience store price versus gas station price is wildly different.
FTR I'm interested in the price of "cheap" bottled water, not Perrier or such.
(I really couldn't even find the price of a - say - "cheap can of Coke" in 1995, which would likely be similarly priced to a bottled water; and again I literally just can't recall how much a "cheap can of Coke" was in the 90s!)
Someone may know the info source I can't find, or indeed, someone with a plain good memory may have the facts!
Again, I was shocked you can't just instantly look up a list "price of X, every year 1970 to present" sort of thing - surprising.
(*) Nowadays paper road maps, I see, are about 10 bucks (wtf!) if bought cheaply online, probably a fair bit more at gas stations. I'd say bottle of Aquafina or such is 3-4 bucks ? at a gas station (but only 1.00 - 1.50 at a supermarket).

Examples of a "gas station -type map", aka a folding, single-sheet paper map in the very typical size. (I don't know a better nomenclature than "gas station -type map".

$10 doesn't seem too outrageous. I have a vague memory of paying $5 last time I bought one, which would have been 2 decades ago at least.  That may have been for an entire road atlas though. Compiling an accurate cartography of roads (using only your own and non-copyrighted public resources) can't be a cheap process, and I can't imagine they move nearly as many units these days to amortize the cost as they used to.

Very generally, it wouldn't seem unreasonable to use an inflation calculator for most common items. There are of course some specialty times, like gasoline and most tech, that it wouldn't be smart to use that for. Particularly things that were far less common then (charging stations), or are largely obsolete today (road maps, payphones, and phone books)

It's only America-adjacent but for "historic prices by year for item X" Statistics Canada does a really good job. According to this the price index for bottled beverages was 0.63 in 1995 and 1.24 today (with Jan 2020 prices indexed to 1.00) so it's easy to estimate price at any particular venue by going there today & then doing some mental math.

great tip @SPavel TY

For the price of a too expensive can of Coke in 1993 I refer you to this classic scene from the movie Falling Down.

@pipe - right :) ironically i worked in advertising in that era and literally did the Coke account and other consumer brands, but, I simply don't remember!

@pipe I think his problem in that movie was that he needed change for a dollar to make a phone call.  The guy running the convenience store told him he had to buy something.  He picked up a Coke (which was $0.50 a can in vending machines where I lived in central Ohio and had been since the mid/early 80's, though you could get it substantially less in 24 packs, iirc).  The owner wanted $0.85 and so he wouldn't be able to make a call with the change.  I think that's what he was throwing this particular bit of his violent tantrum over.

( @JasonPatterson yes that is correct, that was the setup of the scene there )

Note that the price of bottled water can vary dramatically depending on where you buy it, the size, whether it's cold or not, etc. In France for instance, you can buy a 1.5l of brand-name mineral water for about 0.50-0.60 € in supermarkets, while a 0.5l bottle of the same brand in a small convenience shop (e.g. in a train station, airport, or gas station) will easily be sold for several euros! Even in a supermarket that smaller bottle sold in the sandwich aisle will cost a lot more than the 3 times larger bottle in the drinks aisle. Sure, it's cold, but still...

@jcaron Quite (as I mentioned extensively in the Q and also has been mentioned often in comments).  Note though that I, for one, simply plain don't remember either A what those prices were in the 1990s and indeed B if indeed that "price spread of bottled water" effect was or was not similar in the 90s (in the US) {Indeed, you mention France, nor do I remember those two aspects, in re France, in the 1990s.}   (You or others may have a much better memory, if so, I have put the Q on this page! Interestingly only one person on here outright statesd that they could and did remember the hi

storic price in question. [Actually, that answer has possibly been deleted?, which is a shame.]}

I would call those "fold-out maps".

@TonyK good point, IDK any really popular term.

It's not exactly a "road map" but my copy of the 1995 Edition Rand McNally/Chicago Tribune Chicago & Vicinity 6-County StreetFinder has a cover price of $34.95.  (approx 500 pp. hard cover spiral bound).

I don't think those gas station folding maps were still around in 1995. What do the copyright notices say on the ones you have? Gas stations did sell (and I think do still sell) road atlases like the Rand McNally ones other folks have mentioned, but I guess the folding maps were gone by the mid 1980's. AAA still provided them free to AAA members, at least into the mid 1990s, however.

@MarkDominus it's a good point, like phone books, they are a thing of the past. You can certainly still get them (2024) eg https://www.amazon.com/Rand-McNally-Folded-Map-Western/dp/0528028669 but they are little known - and all the famous ones mentioned on this page, Shell etc, are gone from this world.  For younger people today it's just not possible to grasp that you literally couldn't go somewhere without a map.  What a world!

Historic newspapers, the Internet Archive, and librarians are your friends. The following are some (mostly) U.S.-centric sources:

Internet Archive, use the second search box, not the Wayback Machine. If you know the title, use "Search metadata"; if you're searching for text within a newspaper or book, use "Search text contents."
Library of Congress Chronicling America
The Ancestor Hunt list of newspaper collections
Paid subscription sites (NewsBank, Genealogy Bank, Newspapers dot com)
Your local library website > A-Z Databases, search for "Newspaper" or the name of your local newspaper
Most historical materials are not digitized, so you may have to enlist the help of a librarian.

Visit the library in person.
An alternative is to use Interlibrary Loan (ILL) to have a remote librarian obtain the thing you're looking for and send it to your local library. You can even get them to scan a page of a physical newspaper that hasn't previously been scanned. Some libraries may charge a small fee for this service.



I haven't found info on the maps. When I was a child, maps were free at the gas station, but somewhere along the line, gas stations started charging for them, and I don't remember when that shift happened.
I used my library's A-Z Databases to consult the archives for my local newspaper, where I found store-brand bottled water from $0.69 to $0.79 for a ~3/4 liter bottle, and $6.99 for a case of 20-ounce bottles, quantity unstated but possibly 12 bottles.
Here are a couple of ads from 1995 newspapers in Houston, Texas, in the summer months. Randalls is a local grocery chain, and Eckerd was a Florida-based drugstore chain that was acquired by CVS.




The method to obtain the answer is even more valuable than the answer. This is what H:SE should be.

However, archival materials are scattered over the internet, including google books, internet archive, national archives, individual libraries, private organizations, private collections… It would be helpful if you mentioned the access method of your local newspaper archive.

@hym3242 I've added the method I used as well as some others.

I ticked this answer and thanks, since (A) it seems to be the opinion of many on the history site that the The method to obtain the answer is even more valuable than the answer and it's not my site but your site so this should get the tick! (B) the large number of votes - and indeed the first answer to arrive. Thanks!  if only one could tick more than one answer!

For the road maps, if I were you I'd see if my local library has any. They should have a block on them (the front fold for a fold-out, the back page for a road atlas) that has information like copyright date, and suggested retail price.
As Shover mentioned, these tended to be available in gas stations, particularly those servicing major highways and interstates. Personally I preferred using the Road Atlases, which would have a page per US state, and were also sold in most bookstores and chain grocery stores. Not only were they much easier to put away, but they could be used for pretty much any trip I'd ever take, and it was nearly impossible to mess up my navigation so badly that I ended up off the map.
Also, back before electronic navigation many people in the US who were apt to take road trips would join AAA. This provided travelers with both roadside assistance if they suffered a breakdown in a strange area, and with specialized trip maps showing the roads they need to take for their particular trip in a binder, called TripTik's, upon request. Apparently, they now provide some similar service online. This service was (at least when last I saw it used in the 1980's) free to paying members.

Looking at a AAA map from the 1990s (sorry, unable to date it more accurately than this) shows a price of $3.95 printed on it.

I recall AAA used to give the road maps to members for free, at least in California; the price would have been for non-members.

@jeffronicus Yes, these maps were free to AAA members like us. However, they had a nominal price printed on them and that would provide someone with an idea of the cost of maps in those days. For comparison, I found a AAA map from 2011 in our dusty pile of assorted maps that had $5.95 printed on it. That leads me to hypothesize that the $3.95 map I found earlier likely dates to the early 1990s.

The maps also tended to be free at "visitor center" kiosks catering to traffic on major highways (typically interstates) that had just crossed a state border.

I'm an AAA member and I think I can still get paper maps for "free." ("Free" == "I paid the annual membership fee.") Ah, yes, found it on their website: "AAA members get free printed maps for the U.S., North America regions and provinces, all 50 states, most major cities, specialty maps, and more."

@BenVoigt That's still true. As recently as last year, I picked up free paper maps at the Welcome to Arkansas visitor center on I-30 east of Texarkana.

I have a 1999 AAANew Jersey/Pennsylvania  map, "retail value $2.95".

Map prices will vary quite a bit based on the size, complexity, and quality of the map you're looking for.  For example, a search on archive.org for "1995 map cleveland" turned up scans of this detailed map of Cleveland with "$12.95" on the cover. That was fairly standard price for a 100+ page, laminated, book-bound map with that level of detail.  Your standard impossible-to-re-fold flimsy paper map is a bit harder to find since their size makes them difficult to scan.  I found this city map of Newark from 2009 that was labeled "$4.99".  That's about $3.50 in 1995 dollars, which seems about right to my memory for a map that size.  Printing costs dominate the cost for these cheaper maps, so it's all a factor of overall size, paper quality, and number of ink colors.
Most people didn't actually pay for maps, though (at least in my experience). Racks full of brochures and free maps were common sights in gas stations, hotel lobbies, and large rest stops.  Chambers of commerce and other civic groups would publish city maps with local landmarks and tourist attractions marked on them.  The state department of transportation would distribute free maps of the state's highway system, like this 1990 map of Montana. Gas stations would sometimes publish their own maps that had store locations marked on them.  You could even send off for free travel guides from a state's transportation or tourism department.  These were large atlases with high-level as well as detailed regional maps (example for Texas from 1996). There was a decent chance that a gas station on a highway would even have fairly nice maps posted on the wall inside the store for travelers to reference.
As far as bottled water goes, the price depends on how you buy it.  Standard vending machine prices where I lived (per my memory, it's hard to find a source) were 50 cents for a 12oz can and 75 cents for a 20oz bottle. Buying from the cooler in a gas station was roughly the same price, and buying a multi-pack from a grocery store was (per unit) a bit less than half of the vending machine price.  Around the same price ratios as today.

(For maps I meant the "typical" folding sheet "gas station type" maps - example in the question!  I don't know a more common term for that type of map.)

Most people didn't actually pay for maps, though I constantly bought maps of countries, states and "regions" (Example, the classic "Western United States"!). (Call these perhaps "highway maps.)  IMO the widely available free ones you mention which indeed were everywhere tended to be tourist maps for towns/cities, or maybe tourist areas, but not for these type of map maps, which were paid! https://www.etsy.com/listing/881440238/choice-gas-station-maps-vintage. (dozens of listing on ebay etc  ... couldn't see a price!)

(many of the designs from different gas chains were so memorable!  https://www.etsy.com/listing/1621582590/vintage-road-maps-from-american-gas

@Fattie The maps from the transportation department were typically the most accurate, they came from the state's "official" sources. Map records were already heavily digitized by the 90s, so proprietary map data wasn't that useful anymore. The state's official GIS records were free or cheap and most paid-for maps were based off those with some sort of value-add (like overlays of public transport routes or cross-referencing). We'd always stop at the first rest stop after crossing a state line, they would always have the good free maps.

IIRC, Shell's maps were so well-liked that they spun off that division into a separate company. I recall seeing those even into the early 2010's, long after they were gone from stations.

"The maps from the transportation department" could we sight one of those, I'm not sure which ones you mean?  I'd be fascinated. (By transportation department did you mean: https://www.transportation.gov ?) thanks again!

@Fattie: Presumably the individual state's transportation department, not the federal government's.

@Fattie Yes, the states' transportation departments. See the map of Montana linked in my answer for an example.  I'm not aware of the federal DoT producing any maps.  The only federally-produced road maps that I'm aware of are those of federal lands, like national parks (but they're produced by the National Park Service). The feds don't actually own many roads, so it makes a lot more sense for the states to handle the maps.

fantastic info @bta thanks.  its unfair only one answer can be ticked!  key information in here TY

A quick search of eBay finds an actual 1995 AAA map of Michigan marked "Retail Value 4.00", so I would expect a price of around $3.95 from a gas station.
An almost equally quick search finds a mid-1996 NY Times article (behind a paywall) on bottled water that claims:

One-and-a-half-liter bottles range in price from $1.39 to more than
$2.

Then, as now, I would expect the price of bottled water at a gas station to be towards the higher end. Supermarkets towards the lower end, and of course, there is hardly a lower limit to what a supermarket might put a product like that on loss-leader sale for.

WOW!!  GREAT WORK SPEHRO!  I spent an hour on eBay and other memorabilia sites, and I couldn't find one with a price on it, as I mentioned!  Amazing!!!  THE ACTUAL ANSWER!!

Water - so funny, I literally found that same article, but I loathe the NYT so I wouldn't pay their pay wall for the one article :)  Thanks again.  (I don't suppose they mention individual bottles?)  Spectacular touch, Spehro!

@Fattie Thanks. That is about it for individual bottle information. There's aggregate total sales info for the then-leaders of Arrowhead, Poland and Evian, followed by seven others, most of which I've not personally noticed in US outlets (probably because I go for the cheapest stuff if I'm hiking or whatever).

if the 1.5L was buck forty, probably fifty cents for individual drink ("like a coke can, but bottled water") makes sense!

INCREDIBLY HELPFUL as you literally supplied the answer to both questions which I could not find.. I actually thought maps were more like 1.50$ - 2.00$ then; you saved a blunder.  Bounty en route TY !
